# Is there a way to create a 3-dimensional array with a dynamic size?

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't seem to work out how to create an array that is both in three-dimensions and dynamically size; allow me to explain.

I'm working on a gamemode for a popular online multiplayer modification, FiveM. This is more for me to go over C# (I've just started studying cyber security at university and would like to sharpen up on my skills) than it is for me to play around.

I'm trying to create the array like this (I have already done this in Lua)

```
|LicenseID|    |RoleName|RoleR|RoleG|RoleB|Cash|Bank|
|AAAAAAAAA|    | Player | 255 | 255 | 255 | 12 |1452|
|BBBBBBBBB|    | Player | 255 | 255 | 255 | 12 |1452|
|CCCCCCCCC|    | Player | 255 | 255 | 255 | 12 |1452|
|DDDDDDDDD|    | Player | 255 | 255 | 255 | 12 |1452|
```

Referenced in Lua like so

```lua
rName=playerInformation[LicenseID]['RoleName']
rRed=playerInformation[LicenseID]['RoleR']
rGreen=playerInformation[LicenseID]['RoleG']
rBlue=playerInformation[LicenseID]['RoleB']
```

and so on, where LicenseID is `AAAAAAAAA`, `BBBBBBBBB`, etc.

However I would like the array to have the ability to facilitate around 255 entries (in an ideal situation), however 32 works too. Due to the nature of its application, the array may not always be full. 
I'm really stuck because I'm really can't figure out how this could (it may not) be possible.

Comment: Arrays by definition have a fixed size. If you want a dynamic size you want a list or other collection, not an array. If you told us where these “LicenseID”, “RoleR” and such are coming from we may be able to help you.

Comment: In an Object Oriented world, a class and a `List<T>` may be the obvious solution(s), but you didnt tell us anything about constraints such as where that data comes from.  But at least you now have something to research

Comment: When the player joins it will query a database and return the user's information. If there are 32 players, it should have 32 entries in the list. The entries "LicenseID", "RoleR", etc come from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use a Dictionary like that:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{

  public class PlayerInformation
  {
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleR { get; set; }
    public int RoleG { get; set; }
    public int RoleB { get; set; }
    public int Cash { get; set; }
    public int Bank { get; set; }
  }

  public class Licenses : Dictionary<string, PlayerInformation>
  {
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    var licenses = new Lisences();

    licenses.Add("AAAAAAAAA",
                 new PlayerInformation
                 {
                   RoleName = "PLayer",
                   RoleR = 255,
                   RoleG = 255,
                   RoleB = 255,
                   Cash = 12,
                   Bank = 1452
                 });

    licenses.Add("BBBBBBBBB",
                 new PlayerInformation
                 {
                   RoleName = "PLayer",
                   RoleR = 255,
                   RoleG = 255,
                   RoleB = 255,
                   Cash = 12,
                   Bank = 1452
                 });

    foreach ( var item in licenses )
      Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Value.RoleName + ", " + item.Value.Bank);

    Console.ReadKey();

  }

}
```

You can access items like that:

```
var value = licenses[licenseID].RoleR;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll adapt this to take entries from a database and it'll be perfect!